# How to make search for model inside creating other

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have this partial view for searching for publisher but when I'm using it in another form with another actionresult it response for the other like this.

This view is a partial view which I action it in the next one

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("publisherslist",FormMethod.Get))
           { 
           <input type="text" id="q" name="q"/>
            <input type="submit" />
            } 
              @foreach (var i in Model)
        {
         @Publisher.Name
            <br />
           }
```

and I render it in another view

```
         @model ELibrary_Search_Engine.BookModels.Book
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", null, FormMethod.Post, new {enctype= "multipart/form-data" }))
 { 
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                    </div>
                </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "CategoryID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })


        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
                        </div>
                    </div>
               <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
                    <br />
                   <label>Choose Publisher:</label>
                       <br />
                        @Html.Action("publisherslist")
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                    </div>
                    }
```

I want to enable the search for publisher

Comment: Do you have to follow this method to search for publisher ? I mean can we suggest an improvement ? Please name the `views` provided so we don't make incorrect assumptions. What does `Model` return in `publisherslist` view ? what does `Html.RenderPartial("Publisher", i);` do ?

Comment: i correct what you say sorry cause it was bad 
i want the first with its formmethod publisherlist to render in the create view

Comment: NP It's OK. It seems you are trying to search for a publisher in the Create form and then submit it along with the other details. In the current setup it probably will not work, because the search (even if it's correct) returns just plain text. Have you considered using `ajax.get` get to search for the publisher instead. Does the `Book` model have a `PublisherName` property to `bind` ?

Comment: it has list<book-publisher> which contains the publisher

Comment: Please check out @DanielMackenzie answer. It's a suggested approach for your scenario. You need to make sure that you have a property that you can bind in the `Book` model. Like `Book.PublisherName` or `Book.PublisherId` to submit the form for the selected Publisher.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're embedding a form inside of another form.

The best course of action is to use JQuery to populate the list of publishers based on the search string.

**In your Html:**

```
<input type="text" id="q" name="q"/>
<input type="button" onclick="getPublishers" />

<select id="publisher-list">
</select>
```

**In your javascript:**

```
function getPublishers()
{
    //Cache your query string.
    var queryString = $("#q").val();
    //URL of your searching action.
    var url = "/ControllerName/publisherslist?queryString=" + queryString;
    //Clear the current select list.
    $("#publisher-list").empty();

    //Pull the list of publishers.
    $.ajax(
        url : url, 
        success : function(response){
        //Insert the publishers into the select list, make sure to reference the value you want to be displayed from the JSON object
            $("#publisher-list").append($("<option/>", {value: response.Id, text: response.Name}));
        });
}
```

**In your C#**

```
public JsonResult(var queryString)
{
  //TODO: Search logic and return objects in JSON format. 
}
```

I'm assuming your search method is working, you'll just need to format the returned data into a JSON object and this example should work - with some fiddling.

Comment: how i can insert the publisher into select list 
that's the first time i work with json 
and thank you a lot

Comment: I'm not sure how your search works, but something along the lines of: 

var publishers = _db.Publishers.Where(pub => pub.Name.Contains(queryString).ToList();

return Json(publishers);

Change the Model and Parameter names to match yours where appropriate, the javascript then injects the returned values into the select list, just make sure this line: 
$("#publisher-list").append($("<option/>", {value: response.Id, text: response.Name}));
References the correct column names

Comment: No problem! If this solved your question please consider marking this as the answer, have a nice day :)

Comment: actually it didnot response